# Find a matrix $\mathcal X$ that satisfies the equation $\operatorname{tr}(B)A + 3X = BC$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\mathcal{A} = \begin{pmatrix}2&-1&3 \\ 0&4&5\\-2&1&4\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathcal{B} = \begin{pmatrix}8&-3&-5\\0&1&2\\4&-7&6\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathcal{C} = \begin{pmatrix}0&-2&3\\1&7&4\\3&5&9\end{pmatrix}$$
The answer in the book is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\6&0\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't get how $\mathcal X$ can be a $2\times 2$ matrix because you can't add that to a $3 \times 3$ matrix, right? The way I did it was to just multiply $\operatorname{tr}(B) = 15$ by $\mathcal A$ and then I multiplied $\mathcal{BC}$ and solved for $\mathcal X$ from there. The first entry I got was $-16$ but it's supposed to be one. Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: We simply have $X=(BC)/3-5A$, which is not the matrix given there. Are you sure this is the correct exercise number? And yes, the first row is $(-16,-47/3,-26)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning and approach is correct. Your answer should be a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

$(1,1)$-entry of $BC$ is $8(0)-3(1)-5(3)=-3(1+5)=-3(6)$.

$(1,1)$-entry of $tr(B)A$ is $15(2)=3(10)$.

$(1,1)$-entry of $BC-tr(B)A = 3(-16)$$

Hence $(1,1)$-entry of $X$ is $-16$.